# NodeJS streaming JSON from python

Tags: python, json, node.js

I'm creating an API with NodeJS. Every request returns a JSON. Some requests call to a python script and I want to send the JSON generated by python to the user. The code would look like:

```
child = child_process.spawn(cmd, args);

child.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
    res.write(chunk);
});

child.on('error', function(err) {
    res.status(500).json({...});
});

child.on('close', (code) => {
    res.end();
});
```

The problem with this code is that I can't check if the python output is a JSON. Maybe python writes warnings, error...

What can I do to prevent the user will get something different to JSON?.

*EDIT*

Right now my code is:

```
var output = [];

command.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
    output.push(chunk)
});

command.on('close', (code) => {
    var stdout = output.join('');
    json_cmd = tryParseJSON(stdout)
    if (json_cmd)
        res.send(json_cmd)...
});
```

But, I don't want to load all the stdout in a variable. But if I don't do that, I can check if the stdout is a JSON. **Can I force python to print just json?**. Using always json.dumps and a global try catch would be enough?

Thanks.

Comment: Just check if it is JSON, your `stdout` is a string, so parse it with `JSON.parse`. If it fails it is not a JSON structure

Comment: chunk contains a part of the stdout. So, maybe it is not JSON.
chunk1 = {...'color':'bl; chunk2 = ue' ...; chunkN= ...}.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `spawn`, you probably want to use [`exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), which will wait for the Python process to exit and provide you with its output (which you can subsequently try to parse as JSON):

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
...
exec(cmdline, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) return res.status(500).json({...});
  // Try to parse stdout as JSON:
  try {
    res.json(JSON.parse(stdout));
  } catch(e) {
    res.status(500).json({...});
  }
});
```

Comment: exec has a buffer limit. I don't want size limits in the python output. Also, in that way you will have all the stdout in a variable... I prefer to use chunks.

Comment: So how did you want to test the validity of the output if you don't first read it?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible. The solution would be to force python to write only json

Comment: @robertklep can you please see this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66236502/how-to-get-the-processed-csv-file-from-python-and-download-via-link-or-button-in

Comment: @robertklep

please see my issue

Comment: @robertklep
 can you please see this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66236502/how-to-get-the-processed-csv-file-from-python-and-download-via-link-or-button-in

Answer (score 0):

So you need a streaming JSON verifier in NodeJS. The problem is that if you start streaming the json data over the network, and find an error in the JSON halfways, you cannot rollback the traffic to the http headers and change `200 ok` to `500 ise`. If you want to check the output first you have to accumulate it in the server before sending.

Your current code would do the same. If an error event comes the client will receive a 200 ok with a half stdout and a json object at the end. (Or the response object throws an error if you try to set the status code after it has been sent, I don't know how is this case handled.)

Comment: can you please see this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66236502/how-to-get-the-processed-csv-file-from-python-and-download-via-link-or-button-in